# Spring Data Neo4j @Query not returning child nodes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graph, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I've four pojos related by unique relationship.
First **Employee** node:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Employee {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = true)
    private String employeeId;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_POSITION", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Position position;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_SHIFT", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<ShiftDate> shiftDates = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = "RESTRICTION_OF_EMPLOYEE", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<Restriction> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = "PREFERENCE_OF_EMPLOYEE", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<Preference> preferences = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

As you can see, it has four relationship.
My **ShiftDate** pojo looks like:

```
@NodeEntity

public class ShiftDate {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private Date startDt;
    private Date endDt;

    private List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_RESTRICTION", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Restriction> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_PREFERENCE", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Preference> preferences = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now, **Restriction** and **Preference**:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Restriction {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String notes;
}

@NodeEntity
public class Preference {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String notes;
}
```

The problem is when I'm trying to fetch **ShiftDate** details from the **Employee** node, it's returning only ShiftDate data but not the Preference and Restriction Data.

I've tried Spring Data's `List<ShiftDate> getShiftDatesByEmployeeId(String employeeId)` method which doesn't work.

Tried

```
@Query("MATCH (employee:Employee{employeeId:{0}})-[has_shift:HAS_SHIFT]->(shiftDate:ShiftDate)
RETURN shiftDate");
```

still doesn't work. Tried advanced query like

```
@Query("MATCH (employee:Employee)-[has_shift:HAS_SHIFT]->(shiftDate:ShiftDate)-[has_preference:HAS_PREFERENCE]-> (preference:Preference)
WITH employee,shiftDate,preference
MATCH (shiftDate)-[has_restriction:HAS_RESTRICTION]->(restriction:Restriction) WHERE employee.employeeId={0}
RETURN shiftDate,preference,restriction");
```

still not working.

Can anybody tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the relations as well, that way SDN will populate your child objects.

Your **return** clause should look like:

```
RETURN shiftDate, has_preference, preference, has_restriction, restriction
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer